# Foreign key reference with count

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the count of foreign key(author) in order to get the count of total blogs made by a user. But it is showing the incorrect total. Can someone help on how to get the foreign key reference with count. Thanks.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):

     author  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs')
     created_date  =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

     def total_likes_received(user):
         return user.blogs.aggregate(total_likes=Count('likes'))
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return (Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
                                    .order_by('-date')
                                    .annotate(
                      author_total_likes = Count('author__blogs__likes'),
                      author_total_blogs = Count('author__blogs')
                                             )
```

Comment: Why do you use Blogger class instead of Blog ?

Comment: ohh thats a typo. Corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

```
user_id=1
count = Blog.objects.filter(author_id=user_id).count()
```

You will get the count of **`Blog`** instances related to `User` with `id=1`

**Update**

```
aggregation = Blog.objects.values('blog').annotate(count=Count('author'))
```

Comment: i want to get the count for all authors and display it with the blog according to the author of the blog

Comment: It will go in views.py ?
I have tried return (Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
                                    .order_by('-date')
                                    .annotate(
                      
                      author_total_blogs = Count('author')
                                             )
but it doesnt give the correct figure

Comment: You could try it anywhere you want

Comment: Can you show the complete `view`? and How do you plan to display it?

Comment: I have it there. I want to fetch it in author_total_blogs. I have tried your code, it gives the error that 'blog' is not a field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174440/discussion-between-user-and-jerin-peter-george).

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add this and pass the user id when the method is called.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='blogs')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def total_likes_received(user):
        return self.__class__.objects.filter(author_id=user).count()
```